# Zebra FX7500 RFID reader: IoT Connector service to send data through HTTP POST not working

Tags: tags, http-post, rfid, reader, zebra-scanners

In the latest [firmware update](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/operating-system/fx7500-series-operating-system.html) (3.10.30) of the FX7500 RFID reader a new service has been introduced called [IoT Connector](https://zebra-stage.github.io/dcs/rfid/fixedreaders/read2cloud/1-0/new_docs/). This service enables you to transfer RFID tag data through the HTTP POST method. I've configured the endpoint for the tag data AND management data to a [webhook.site](https://webhook.site/) URL.

When I enable the IoT Connector service the management data is sent out to the webhook.site URL but not the tag data. I assume that my RFID reader and antenna are not scanning.

Somebody know if i have missed any configurations?

Answer (score 1):

You have to issue a Start REST API to get tag data, and set the Management and Control interface to Local REST to receive REST API calls. Please see documentation available from FX9600 support site - https://zebradevs.github.io/rfid-ziotc-docs/

Comment: how to issue a Start REST API?